# busybox initramfs ubuntu 18.04 system crash repeatedly

Tags: data-recovery, initramfs, media

I hope you all do not mind, I am flabbergasted and need assistance.
I continuously install Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 on a Lenovo desktop as it's only operating system. At first I had no issues for months.

Now everytime I install it after a crash that boots to busybox initramfs prompt it would work until I installed the DVD libs and then freeze up and only boots to the busybox initramfs prompty.

It never gives me the option to re-install using the live USB, it can not detect any OS at all, I used to encrypt the drive and thought that was the cause so the last two times I have not encrypted the drive, still it detects no OS and no data other than the vm file system when I try using testdisk/PhotoRec, it's like the previous installation does not exist.

The problem is that this time it gets stuck and hangs when starting up the installation process and will not even reinstall.

It's really important that I get some of the data that was saved in the documents folder of the last installation and hopefully find a way to keep it from crashing to busybox initramfs prompt in the future.

Comment: If your data are still there, you can boot via "Test ubuntu" and then mount the laptop drive and then backup them.

Comment: I eventually got it to re-install again, and the data was not there, I am not sure why exactly

Comment: Your data is gone, probably because you forgot to uncheck the "format" checkbox during the reinstall. If you're having to constantly reinstall, your hard disk is probably going bad. Open the `Disks` app and check the SMART Data & Tests on your hard disk.

Comment: I keep running into so many issues like this one, and it always comes down to having Dual Boot issues but I do not have a dual boot system, one of the hard drives at one time had Windows 10 on it, long ago, but it's been formatted re-partitioned so many times, it doesn't even have a NTFS partition anymore..